# How to connect Libreoffice Base with mysql on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, mysql, libreoffice

I have a virgin install of 20.04 (instead of upgrading from 18.04, and older versions). mysql works, but I cannot use LibreOffice Base to connect to my database in mysql. This worked well in 18.04. I searched the web, tried various apt installs, but still cannot connect. Typical errors are "...org.mariadb.jdbc:Driver..." or "...oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver..." could not...

Update: I have downloaded mariadb-java-client-2.6.0.jar from https://downloads.mariadb.org/connector-java/2.6.0/
It is a deb package, so I installed it with `sudo apt install ./mariadb-java-client-2.6.0.jar`.
At this point things were strange. First, I had to rename the installed file in `/usr/share/java` by stripping the "-2.6.0" from the .jar file. Then connection either succeeded or not. When it did not succeed it complained about encryption, public key, etc. However, after signing on to the same database from mysql workbench then connection from LO Base worked.

Technically the problem is solved, but I cannot post this as "Answer" because of the idiosyncrasy of on or off connection. I'm sure there is a more elegant and straightforward solution out of the box when 20.04 is installed with LibreOffice Base.

Comment: Do you have Java installed on the the new OS? Is there a Java version selected in your Libre Office settings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this and it helped me dig a little deeper to find the answer. What you need to do is:

1. Install the MySQL or MariaDB jar file, for ubuntu do:

   `sudo apt install libmariadb-java`
2. Open **Tools** >**Options** >**LibreOffice** >**Advanced**
3. Click the **Class Path** Button
4. Click **Add Archive**
5. Find your **jar** file, mine was in `/usr/share/java`
   Then when you come to the screen in Base that has the test class button, it should validate for you.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, a cleaner way to do it. Mine has been working OK, but wanted to test your suggestion, and renamed may jar file to backup (just in case), then proceeded with your instructions. It works. It looks like the newly installed file is a later version, slightly smaller size. Th important thing is to do install libmariadb-java.